# Lock Orientation in WebView while playing video or MPMoviePlayerController in ios 5

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing video in ios 5. My application supports landscapemode. I want to lock orientation to landscape when my application is playing video in full screen no matter if I play in `Webview` or `MPMoviePlayerController`.

I had created a subclass of MPMoviePlayerController and implement `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` but as I suspect this is not being called coz this method is available in `UIViewController`.

Please help me to lock orientation of Video player.

EDIT 3:
Here is My Code:

```
- (void)showTransferedVideo:(NSNotification*)notification {

viewFileDisplay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[viewFileDisplay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.70]];

NSString *imagePath =  [((MobileJabberAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).strFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [notification object]]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
UIWebView *objWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(212, 152, 600, 400)];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[objWebView loadRequest:req];
[viewFileDisplay addSubview:objWebView];
[self.view addSubview:viewFileDisplay];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Issue occurs only in ios 5 and when I play video in fullscreen. I want to lock orientation fullScreen

Thanks

Comment: You must be creating the webview/Movie player in a different View Controller. Why dont you implement BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation in it?

Comment: I already done this but webview plays video in quicktime player. Can we control QuickTimePlayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can lock the player you get from using a `UIWebView` to landscape like that. I suggest you subclass `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` like you have in your class you've shown to only support landscape orientation. Then use that to play your video.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerContrroller subclass don't call `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrieantation:`. I tried this too.

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerViewController` *not* `MPMoviePlayerController`. Note the difference - you need to subclass the view controller, not the player itself.